# JS date object is not parsing correctly

Tags: javascript, date

We currently save the date in this format: `12/12/2011 8:00:00 PM`.

When I parse it in JS Date object, it converts into this: `Tue, 13 Dec 2011 00:00:00 GMT`.

I do not believe this is a timezone issue because we are -4 GMT and it does not add up.  Any ideas?

```
var start = new Date("12/12/2011 8:00:00 PM");
alert("12/12/2011 8:00:00 PM");
alert(start.toUTCString());
```

Comment: 8:00 PM is exactly 4 hours before 0:00. What's the problem?

Comment: Is the original date string meant to be in UTC/GMT as well? Cause, as is, `Date` assumes it to be a "local" date string.

Comment: Yes, what is wrong with that? 20:00:00 is 8pm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to add up perfectly. "12/12/2011 8:00:00 PM" in GMT-4 is exactly  "Tue, 13 Dec 2011 00:00:00 GMT".

**EDIT**
Use toLocaleString to get the date and time in your local time zone.

```
start.toLocaleString()
```

Comment: I see... thanks for the answer.  How do I convert it to my local GMT -4 if I need to use the getTime() functionality?

Comment: What is the output that you are looking for?

Comment: Actually it's correct, thanks, I forgot to take into account 12/24 hour display.